# Why does a JCR SQL 2 Query for nt:unstructured also return cq:PageContent nodes?

Tags: aem, jcr

I have the following JCR SQL 2 query:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured] as node
         WHERE isDescendantNode(node, '/content/some/root/path')
         AND # EXTRA CONDITIONS
```

and the result set, along with a bunch of `nt:unstructured` nodes, returns a lot of nodes with the `cq:PageContent` primary type. When inspected in CRX DE, it's clear that their `jcr:primaryType` is `cq:PageContent`, not `nt:unstructured`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each node type in JCR [can have supertypes](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/spec/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.7.1.2%20Supertypes).

> **3.7.1.2 Supertypes**
>
> A node type has zero or more supertypes. Supertypes are specified by name.

which can be organised into an [inheritance hierarchy](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/spec/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.7.6%20Node%20Type%20Inheritance).

In case of this particular query, where the `nt:unstructured` node type is used, `cq:PageContent` nodes appear in the result set because their `jcr:primaryType` is a subtype of `nt:unstructured`.

This is described in [the documentation for AEM custom node types](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/platform/custom-nodetypes.html?lang=en#cq-pagecontent).

> `[cq:PageContent] > nt:unstructured, mix:title, mix:created, cq:OwnerTaggable, sling:VanityPath, cq:ReplicationStatus, sling:Resource orderable`
>
> - `cq:template (string)`
> - `cq:allowedTemplates (string) multiple`
> - `pageTitle (string)`
> - `navTitle (string)`
> - `hideInNav (boolean)`
> - `onTime (date)`
> - `offTime (date)`
> - `cq:lastModified (date)`
> - `cq:lastModifiedBy (string)`
> - `cq:designPath (string)`
> - `jcr:language (string)`

The query, depending on the other conditions, is likely to return nodes with other types explicitly listed as the `jcr:primaryType`, which also inherit from `nt:unstructured`. Some examples include: `cq:EditConfig`, `dam:AssetContent`, `cq:LiveSyncAction` and many more.